# Scalaj Data Urlencode

Tags: scala, scalaj-http

When I execute a POST request using curl, it looks this way:

```
curl -k -X POST \    
--header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \    
--header "Accept: application/json" \    
--data-urlencode "grant_type=urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey" \    
--data-urlencode "apikey=<somekey>" \    
"https://iam.bluemix.net/identity/token"
```

In the `scalaj-http` library, I know we can add `header`, but I don't see a way to add `data-urlencode` as an option. How can I add this? I need it for my POST Request to be successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`postForm`](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http#simple-form-encoded-post) like so

```
Http("https://iam.bluemix.net/identity/token")
  .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  .header("Accept", "application/json")
  .postForm(Seq(
    "grant_type" -> "urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey", 
    "apikey" -> "somekey"))
  .asString
```